# WPF Image Control Source Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, image, binding, properties

I am new to WPF and C#, I try to implement the following feature, but failed after a lot of attempts. Can anyone help me out?

I have an image control:

```
<Image Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ImageEditor"  Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="Both"/>
```

I want to bind the source of this image control to a static property of another class (`ImageHandler`)

```
class ImageHandler
{
    public static BitmapImage ImageToDisplay { get; set; }

    public ImageHandler(){}

    .... //other codes
}
```

So whenever I do something in the `ImageHandler` class, and update the `ImageToDisplay` property, my image control will display the new image.

I have try several methods, but none of them achieved this goal. The following shows one of my failed attempts.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ImageHandler x:Key="ImageHandler"></local:ImageHandler>
</Window.Resources>

<Image Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ImageEditor" Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="Both" 
    Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=ImageHandler},
    Path=ImageToDisplay,Mode=TwoWay}">
</Image>
```

Comment: Why does the property have to be static? It would be easier to have a non-static property and access the ImageHandler resource object for updates.

Comment: Yes the use of _static_ attribute is not clear here.

Comment: I have a CommandHandler class, which handles Open, Save, SaveAs etc, The following codes are what I want to achieve:

Comment: public static void OpenCommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)    
{
                var openImage = new OpenFileDialog();
                openImage.Title = "Select an image";
                Nullable<bool> result = openImage.ShowDialog();
                if (result == true)
                {
                    ImageHandler.ImageToDisplay = ImageHandler.LoadImage(openImage.FileName);

                }
        }

Comment: Without static attribute, I don't know how to save newly opened image to the same ImageToDisplay property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement either `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `ImageHandler`

For dependency property :

```
class ImageHandler : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BitmapImage imageToDisplay;
    public BitmapImage ImageToDisplay
    {
        get { return imageToDisplay; }
        set
        {
            if (imageToDisplay != value)
            {
                imageToDisplay = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImageToDisplay");
            }
        }
    }

    public ImageHandler() { }

    // .... Other codes

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

However, to implement it, I had to remove the `static` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I get my goal met. Instead of using static property , I create an static property of ImageHandler class in App.cs. And Using your codes, I can updated my ImageToDisplay dynamically.